# bootstrap nested checkboxes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, nested-checkboxes

The following is js code for nested checkboxes I use it to my Laravel project it select parent when I check the child and select all children when checking the parent.
can anyone please help me how to apply this js code but remove the select all of children checkboxes.

```
$(function() {

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(checkboxChanged);

  function checkboxChanged() {
    var $this = $(this),
        checked = $this.prop("checked"),
        container = $this.parent(),
        siblings = container.siblings();

    container.find('input[type="checkbox"]')
    .prop({
        indeterminate: false,
        checked: checked
    })
    .siblings('label')
    .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
    .addClass(checked ? 'custom-checked' : 'custom-unchecked');

    checkSiblings(container, checked);
  }

  function checkSiblings($el, checked) {
    var parent = $el.parent().parent(),
        all = true,
        indeterminate = false;    

    $el.siblings().each(function() {
      return all = ($(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") === checked);
    });

    if (all && checked) {
      parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .prop({
          indeterminate: false,
          checked: checked
      })
      .siblings('label')
      .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
      .addClass(checked ? 'custom-checked' : 'custom-unchecked');

      checkSiblings(parent, checked);
    } 
    else if (all && !checked) {
      indeterminate = parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0;

      parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .prop("checked", checked)
      .prop("indeterminate", indeterminate)
      .siblings('label')
      .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
      .addClass(indeterminate ? 'custom-indeterminate' : (checked ? 'custom-checked' : 'custom-unchecked'));

      checkSiblings(parent, checked);
    } 
    else {
      $el.parents("li").children('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .prop({
          indeterminate: true,
          checked: false
      })
      .siblings('label')
      .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
      .addClass('custom-indeterminate');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can't you take time to format the question properly?

Comment: https://codepen.io/fsbdev/pen/nILhu

here is the code 
in the preview if you tried to check the parent checkbox all children will be checked  
I want to disable this select all option, I tried but i didnt reach the right answer